# Reprojecting EPSG:5514 to EPSG:3857 for use in Leaflet

Tags: leaflet, gdalwarp, epsg, gdal-translate, gdal2tiles

I have one JPG (170 MB) and JGW file of a small area projected in EPSG:5514 (Image provider told me.)

JGW file:

```
                 0.1250000
                 0.0000000
                 0.0000000
                -0.1250000
           -584310.1875000
          -1213026.9375000
```

I am trying to create a custom map tiles for Leaflet in EPSG:3857.

I have tried to convert source JPG to TIFF

```
gdal_translate -of Gtiff -a_srs EPSG:5514 -co COMPRESS=JPEG -co JPEG_QUALITY=100 -co PHOTOMETRIC=YCBCR source.jpg output.tiff
```

Then I have used gdalwarp for reprojection

```
gdalwarp -of Gtiff -s_srs EPSG:5514 -t_srs EPSG:3857 -co COMPRESS=JPEG -co JPEG_QUALITY=100 -co PHOTOMETRIC=YCBCR output.tiff output_3857.tiff
```

Then I have transformed it to JPEG and changed the image size for zoom level

```
gdal_translate -of JPEG -outsize 16384 17700 output_3857.tiff output_zoom6.jpg
```

As a last step I generated the tiles

```
gdal2tiles -p raster -w all output_zoom6.jpg tiles
```

But if I use these tiles in Leaflet and I try to add a marker to the map, marker is in the wrong place...

[image: Leaflet]

Marker should be near the center of the image... If I use OpenStreet map tiles, marker is in the correct position, so my tiles are on the wrong place.

Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

Comment: It's difficult to see the offset with the information you've shown. Can you please change your screenshot, so it shows four markers where the four corners of the raster image would be? That'd help a bit more.

Comment: I think GDAL is not reading the info in jgw file. Use -projwin ulx uly lrx lry to give the coordinates of corner.

Answer (score 0):

On stackoverflow there is a [Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75589550/12558456) which imports a georefered image (more precisely a  jpg/jgw combination) directly in to leaflet.

But i think your main problem is that you do not get the jgw to edgecoordinates calculation right, which is explained [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/120659/184152) more precisly.